# How do you get labelled enumerated items to align at the original starting points

Tags: enumerate

I have the following code: it generates three lines the labelled enumerate items, and three lines without any additional labeling

```
\begin{enumerate}
    \item [\bfseries{[Item 1 - Meatloaf]}]  
    \item [\bfseries{[Item 2 - Rubberduck]}]    
    \item [\bfseries{[Item 3 - Crushed Eggs]}]
\end{enumerate}

\begin{enumerate}
    \item 
    \item   
    \item 
\end{enumerate}
```

Below is the end result:
[image]

As you can see, the labels did not start at where it is supposed to start, instead it started moving left, and it is completely out of the page! Why Latex why?

Ideally, I want something like this:

[image]

Can this be done?

Sample Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{amsthm}     


\begin{document}


\section{Introduction}


\begin{enumerate}
    \item [\bfseries{[Item 1 - Meatloaf]}]  
    \item [\bfseries{[Item 2 - Rubberduck]}]    
    \item [\bfseries{[Item 3 - Crushed Eggs]}]
\end{enumerate}

\begin{enumerate}
    \item 
    \item   
    \item 
\end{enumerate}


\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{references}
\end{document}
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: PLS, provide a MWE document to test your code.

Comment: Is there anything listed at the `\item`s? Including the manually enumerated ones?

Comment: @Werner You means additional sentences/objects after \items? No, but the result is the same if some stuff were added at the \items. I'm trying to figure out how to align "Item 1, ..." with "1,2,3..." that are automatically generated by enumerate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `align=left` thanks to [`enumitem`](http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}

\begin{enumerate}[align=left]
  \item [\bfseries{[Item 1 - Meatloaf]}]
  \item [\bfseries{[Item 2 - Rubberduck]}]
  \item [\bfseries{[Item 3 - Crushed Eggs]}]
\end{enumerate}

\begin{enumerate}[align=left]
  \item
  \item
  \item
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

---

Some box manipulation also allows for the placement of elements in alignment with the subsequent list:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}

\begin{enumerate}
  \item [\rlap{\bfseries{[Item 1 - Meatloaf]}}\phantom{1.}]
  \item [\rlap{\bfseries{[Item 2 - Rubberduck]}}\phantom{1.}]
  \item [\rlap{\bfseries{[Item 3 - Crushed Eggs]}}\phantom{1.}]
\end{enumerate}

\begin{enumerate}
  \item
  \item
  \item
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Latex packages were the Iphone apps before Iphone apps.